# Rolling 5 dice, probability of a double.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Trying to grasp some basic counting problems, but I have a hard time developing some intuition.

For example, if you roll 5 dice, the chance of getting a pair is 5 choose 2. But why? I can't wrap my head around it. Is this a shorthand for some more elaborate calculation? There are 6^5 total possibilities. How does this factor in to this? How does the '5' relate to this, apart from the 5 dice of course. Why aren't the outcomes a factor? Are these 'hidden'?

Comment: "*The chance of getting a pair is $5$ choose $2$*"  What?  $5$ choose $2=10$ can't possibly be a probability.  You must have heard wrong.

Comment: The probability that among five dice being rolled, exactly two come up as the same number and the remaining three are all different numbers than eachother and different than the aforementioned two will be $\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{6^5}$

Comment: Perhaps my wording is wrong. Getting exactly two 2's is stated as '5 choose 2' = 10 ways to get two 2's. Does this make more sense? By the way the others can be three 3's for all that matters. Its specifically about getting exactly two 2's.

Comment: If you are asking for the probability that exactly two $2$'s occur and the remaining three dice show numbers other than $2$'s, possibly repeated, this would occur with probability $\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5}{6^5}$.  If you require the remaining three dice all be different that would be $\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{6^5}$.  The phrase "$5$ choose $2$", written as $\binom{5}{2}$, is the number of ways of selecting a two-element subset of a 5-element set.

Comment: First, to approach each of these calculations, make the temporary assumption that each die is a different color.  One is color $a$, another is color $b$, etc... on up to color $e$.  $\binom{5}{2}$ appears in each of the previously mentioned calculations as a part of multiplication principle in deciding which two colors out of the five dice are those colors who match (or who both show the number two in the later example).

Comment: I discussed all the cases in my answer to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772282/probability-of-exactly-three-of-a-kind-in-a-roll-of-5-dice/2772378?noredirect=1#comment5717464_2772378).

Comment: Thanks you both. I'm going to digest these answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 pair -- (which means that we are excluding 2-pair, 3-off a kind, etc)

We will see 4 different numbers.

$6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$

one of those numbers is paired up.

Now we need to think about shuffling the dice.

It helps if you think of the dice as being different colors.  This way it is more obvious why a $(x,x,x,y,y)$ is different from a $(y,x,x,y,x)$  i.e. same numbers in different order.

There are ${5\choose 2}$ ways to "shuffle the dice."

$6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot{5\choose 2} = 3600$

Answer (score 2):

The probability for rolling one pair (and three singles) is: the probability for selecting **four from six** values, of which **one from these four** is for a pair, and arranging these as the outcomes among the roll of five dice.   By arranging we mean: select **two from five** dice for the pair, and a die for each single among the **three** that remain.

$$\left.\dbinom 64\dbinom 41\dbinom 5{2}3!\middle/6^5\right.~=~\dfrac{5!^2}{2!^2~3!~6^4}$$

Thus is where the numbers originate